# Eclipse Subversive/Subclipse pre-commit hook

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I want Eclipse to run my local Maven build/test before committing my changes to my SVN repository. I have no control over server side commit hooks, but I want to introduce my own client side hooks for my team.

I know about [pre-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) and I am using [Eclipse Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) on a custom `Eclipse Luna`.

Is this feature not supported or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook scripts are executed on server side only. [TortoiseSVN is capable of running client side hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks), however this feature is unique to TortoiseSVN and won't work when committing from Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pre-commit hooks are primarily supported by SVN on server-side. However, with a little bit of creativity you can also implement them on the client side within Eclipse.

We have had both Subversive and Subclipse for custom pre-commit hooks:

- Solution for Subversive: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=173903&goto=1726585&#msg_1726585
- Solution for Subclipse (a bit hacky, though): https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/discussions/238#discussioncomment-3335820